# client bases authentication via certificate signed by ROOT CA

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, pki

I have generated a ROOT CA and can successfully use it for client based authentication:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -subj "$SUBJECT"  -days 3650 -keyout root_ca.key -out root_ca.crt
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -subj "$SUBJECT_CLIENT" -out client.csr -keyout client.key 
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in client.csr -CA root_ca.crt -CAkey root_ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 730
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12 -passout pass:
```

(in $SUBJECT_CLIENT the OU is different.
In webserver (apache):

```
  SSLVerifyClient on
  SSLCACertificateFile conf/root_ca.crt
```

`root_ca.crt` imported as authority and `client.p12` as personal certificate in the browser (firefox, chromium)

Now I have created an intermediate CA:

```
openssl req  -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -subj "$SUBJECT_INTER" -keyout intermediateCA.key -out intermediateCA.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in intermediateCA.csr -CA root_ca.crt -CAkey root_ca.key -CAcreateserial -out intermediateCA.crt -days 1095
```

and use it (`intermediateCA.crt`) in the webserver instead of the `root_ca.crt`.
`$SUBJECT` and `$SUBJECT_INTER` differ in the CN.

Unfortunately the web-browser (and webserver) are reporting errors when trying to access the website using `client.p12`.

P.S.:
Later I want to use client certificates sign by the intermediate CA for certain users. Using `client_intermediate.p12` one should be able to access only the web-side with the `intermediateCA.crt` while other users using only `client.p12` should be able to access websites using `intermediateCA.crt` and websites using `root_ca.crt`.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -subj "$SUBJECT_INTER" -out client_intermediate.csr -keyout client_intermediate.key 
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in client_intermediate.csr -CA intermediateCA.crt -CAkey intermediateCA.key -CAcreateserial -out client_intermediate.crt -days 730
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -in client_intermediate.crt -inkey client_client_intermediate.key -out client_intermediate.p12 -passout pass:
```

Comment: _"are reporting errors"_.  That's a little vague?

Comment: Sorry – the intention was to focus on the certificate generation / signing etc. - so I neglecting the error message.

From Firefox (90.0):
`Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to subdomain.my-domain.xx. SSL_ERROR_RX_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED_ALERT`

Nothing from apache (2.4.47 )

Comment: SSL_ERROR_RX_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED_ALERT is shown when your browser didn't submit a client certificate.  Were you given the option to select one?  Also, Firefox likes to cache previous efforts, so make sure you clear the cache: Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Cookies and Site Data -> Clear Data...

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here.

1st, while you've generated an intermediate CA, you've not signed the client certificate with it.  Using this intermediate CA certificate to verify the client is therefore guaranteed to fail as it's not in the chain.  If you want `client.p12` to verify, then the `SSLCACertificateFile` must point to the client's issuer - the Root CA.  If you change it to point to the intermediate CA then Apache will look for that certificate's issuer (the Root CA is listed as the issuer within the intermediate CA) and not find it - hence the error.

---

You can confuse matters by having non-standard attributes and extensions in your certificates.  Just for clarity, the options below do work with certificates similar to the following:

- Root CA:  Subject = Issuer = "Root CA", basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
- Intermediate CA: Subject = "Intermediate CA", Issuer = "Root CA", basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
- Client 1: Subject = "Client 1", Issuer = "Root CA", keyUsage = digitalSignature & keyAgreement
- Client 2: Subject = "Client 2", Issuer = "Intermediate CA", keyUsage = digitalSignature & keyAgreement

Obviously, you can alter the names to suit your environment.

If you want to insert an intermediate CA in the chain and only accept client certificates signed by this intermediate, then you can use the [Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqexpr) directive to filter the client certificates by an attribute, such as the OU.  You then issue client certificates with specific OU values depending on which website you wish them to access.

As you don't have a OU in your example above, the following will ensure that the client certificate is signed by the intermediate CA, not the root, by checking the issuer's Common Name:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>

Require expr %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN} == "Intermediate CA"

...

</Directory>
```

The above assumes that `$SUBJECT_INTER` was set to *Intermediate CA* and your directory is `/var/www/html/`.  You will need to ensure that this doesn't interfere with, or is affected by, other `Require` directives (such as a `Require all granted` hidden in some config) otherwise you'll be chasing your tail for quite a while.  The expression variables you can use are listed [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars).  You can use variations on this in each virtual host to check that the issuer is the intermediate CA or the root CA, or any other certificate attribute.  For example, if you want to permit access to client signed by either the root CA or the intermediate CA, you could use:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>

<RequireAny>
    Require expr %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN} == "Intermediate CA"
    Require expr %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN} == "Root CA"
</RequireAny>    

...

</Directory>
```

Be careful, as this may interfere with, or may be affected by, other `Require` directives somewhere else within your configuration.

---

An alternative method is to generate multiple Root CAs for client authentication - one per website (or group of websites).  You then apply the `SSLCACertificateFile` per virtual host, pointing to the relevant Root CA certificate. You could also potentially add other directives, such as `SSLVerifyDepth`, per virtual host too.

---

Note that you really need to revise your understanding of certificates before you do anything serious with this.  As they currently stand, those certificates are not very secure.  For example, the client certificate you've generated are version 1 certificates which can therefore act as a CA and potentially sign other client certificates behind your back.  You should create client certificates as version 3 certificates without the Basic Constraints extension.

Of course, if you're just experimenting, you can ignore this last bit.

Comment: 1: That error means there is a certificate missing from the chain. As the certificate signed by the root works, that suggests that you have the correct root in Apache.  That only leaves the possibility of a missing intermediate.  Did you configure that in your client?

Comment: The client cert and intermediate cert are added to the browser, the root cert is configured in your web server. `SSL_ERROR_RX_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED_ALERT` is the browser passing a message from the server saying that it (the server) was expecting a client certificate.  Check your server configuration for additional `Require` blocks. as they may interfere with the ones you've added.

Comment: It  works if `Require all granted` and `AllowOverride none` statements are removed from general blocks in e.g. `http.conf`.

Comment: Client certificates acting the other way round than CAs: If the ROOT CA is set in the server (as `SSLCACertificateFile`) it will accept all client certificates – the ones signed by the ROOT CA directly and the ones signed by an intermediate CA.  If the intermediate CA is set it will accept only client certificates signed by the intermediate CA. Having 2 Root-CA as 1  `SSLCACertificateFile`, both client certificates (signed by ROOT CA1 and the one signed by the ROOT CA2) can access.     
For a certificate chain generate 2 Sub CAs from one ROOT CA and handle both in one file to the server.